# how to use intersection in a db_query?

Tags: database

i want to select elements that exist on table_A and not in table_b, in other words, how to make the sql "intersect" in a drupal select query please ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, just using :

```
$check = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT A.something FROM {table_A} as A
    where something not in (
    SELECT  B.something FROM {table_B} as B)
    ")->fetchField();
```